# pass multiple strings to ruby starts_with?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

I have this code

```
if self.name.starts_with?('Bronze') || self.name.starts_with?('Silver') ||self.name.starts_with?('Gold')
```

Is there a way to pass all of these strings in one go rather than lots of OR as I may have to expand on this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[`String#start_with?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-start_with-3F) accepts arbitrary number of arguments. You don't need to use `||`.

```
'Silver medal'.start_with?('Bronze', 'Silver', 'Gold')
# => true
'Hello medal'.start_with?('Bronze', 'Silver', 'Gold')
# => false
```

Comment: I had no idea, and apparently it's been like that since I should have known better!

Answer (score 1):

<strike>No, `start_with` takes a string or regex.</strike>

I'd find the continuously-expanding regex annoying.

Until I discovered I was [totally wrong as per @falsetru](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28090868/438992), I'd have done it like this:

```
%w[Bronze Silver Gold].any? { |s| name.start_with? s }
```

I'd put the array of words into a variable or constant (or method, I suppose), though.

Then I'd put the logic into a method on whatever it is with the `name` property, the name of which depends on context. This makes this trivially testable, extensible, and encapsulated.

```
def precious_metal?
    self.name.starts_with? precious_metals
end

...

if precious_metal?
  # Some logic
end
```